# understanding while loop in code to find the smallest common multiple

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Could anyone explain/break-down code line by line from *while* loop in this code? I am going through 'find the smallest common multiple' challenge on freecodecamp. I also have added comments as far as i understood.

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1])
  var max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1])
  var range = []

  for(var i = min; i<=max; i++){
    range.push(i); //array of numbers between min and max
  }

  var a = Math.abs(range[0]) //absolute position of negative nums from 0

  for(var j=1; j<range.length; j++){
    var b = Math.abs(range[j]); //iterating range array
    var c = a;

    while(a && b){ //filtering 0. will continue looping as long as a and b is NOT 0
      if(a>b) { 
        a = a%b; //then we will change the value of a to the remainder of a/b
      } else {
        b= b%a;  //changing the value of b 
      }
    }

    a = Math.abs(c*range[j] /(a + b)); 
  }

  return a;
}

smallestCommons([1,5]);
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a pretty good grasp of it. What part exactly are you struggling on? `a = a%b`? That's known as [**Modulo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), to give you a push in the right direction :)

Comment: That seems like something you should look up and do yourself, if you want to learn. Note that understanding the math behind modulo will be helpful. BTW, your comment on `var a` makes no sense.

Comment: thanks @ObsidianAge! i understand 'a = a%b;' will change the value of a to the remainder of a/b, but i just can't follow the logic behind it ha..

Comment: No problem! The documentation is admittedly a little confusing, so just remember that modulo is simply just `a / b` ...and the **remainder** is what you care about. In `a = a % b`, you divide `a` by `b` and store the remainder in whatever is to the left of the equals (in this case it's overriding `a`). For example, `5 % 2` would be `1`, because `2` goes in to  `5` twice, with `1` left over.

Comment: @ObsidianAge thanks again!! i do know how remainder works, i don't follow what the while loop is trying to get. i agree with netmage that i need to figure it out by myself but it's a bit agonizing haha..

Comment: That while loop (and some surrounding code) is an implementation of the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for finding the greatest common divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the algorithm loops through all the numbers, and computes a running smallest common multiple by multiplying the current running SCM by any new factors present only in the next number (e.g. the factors left after dividing the current number by the GCD(running SCM, current number)).

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
// find the smallest common multiple of all the integers from arr[0] to arr[1]

  var min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]); // get the starting number
  var max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]); // get the ending number
  var range = []; // array of all the numbers

  for(var i = min; i<=max; i++){
    range.push(i); //array of numbers between min and max
  }

  var a = Math.abs(range[0]); // start with first number

  for(var j=1; j<range.length; j++) { // compute over remaining numbers in range
    var b = Math.abs(range[j]); // get the next number to process
    var c = a; // remember starting point for end

    while(a && b){ // find the GCD of a & b
      if(a>b) { 
        a = a%b;
      } else {
        b = b%a; 
      }
    }
    // the GCD will be in a or b, whichever is not zero

// compute the smallest common multiple of the numbers from range[0] to range[j]
// by multiplying in the remaining factors after removing the GCD
// which is range[j] / (a+b) since either a or b is the GCD
    a = Math.abs(c*range[j] /(a + b));
  }

  return a;
}
```